# How to detect MySQLi initialization error

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

In my website I am initializing DB connection using values read from config file, like this:

```
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($databaseInfo->MySQL_Host, $databaseInfo->MySQL_User, $databaseInfo->MySQL_Pass, $databaseInfo->MySQL_Db);
```

(for the record, values are being read from file properly and when everything is OK, db connection works just fine)

then I ask whether an error occurred during creating MySQLi object:

```
if (($this->mysqli!=null)&&($this->mysqli->errno == 0)) {
```

if no, then I want to set an error variable and handle it later in the code...I want this check only passes when no problem occurred...I thought **"errno"** variable provides sufficient check...

but apparently not, because regardless any error, I produce in config file, the code still jumps into "everything is fine" branch...obviously PHP produce a lot of warnings and finally it crashes on some fatal error related to the fact database doesn't work as expected

so my question is - how to set up this DB connection initial check properly to avoid such situation?

Comment: I believe you can check  the mysqli `connect_error` property. Or you can catch the exception and handle appropriately.

Comment: thanks, man...checking if `connect_error == NULL` works better

Answer (score 0):

From PHP Manual, try this:

```
if (!$mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If using PHP OOP

```
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
  }
  ?>
```

If using procedural style PHP

```
 if (!$link) {
  die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  ?>
```